# Javascript on backtrack

Tags: javascript, apache, ubuntu

I am running a completetely stock installation of Backtrack 5 R2 (ubuntu) with apache 2.2.14. 
And I tried to run a simple index.html file with some javascript code in it.
For some reason the javascript code does not appear. I am running a completely standard version of apache I have not changed a single configuration file. So why is my javascript code not appearing??

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using other browser?

Please make sure extension [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) was Disabled in FireFox!

(NoScript allows JavaScript, Java and other executable content to run only from trusted domains of your choice)